# How to properly pass objects by value in to functions

Tags: python, image, opencv, deep-copy, pass-by-value

i have a recursive function that has complex arguments like arrays and dictionaries of objects. 
this is the the main recursive function,

```
def finish_top_line(puzzle,result,corner,edge,results):
    min_loss, min_index = 0, 0
    loss_dic = {}
    a_dict = {}
    pieces = {}
    i = len(list(result.keys()))
    print(len(results)," : ",i)
    if i == 1 or i == 25:
        corner.remove(result[i - 1])
    else:
        edge.remove(result[i - 1])
    if i == 25:
    elif i == 24:    
        for index in corner:
            find_corner(puzzle[index], 1,puzzle[result[i-1]])
            result[i] = index
        print("done with 24")
        final = show_results(result, puzzle)
        j = len(results)
        r = ResultSet()
        r.puzzle = puzzle
        r.result = result
        r.corners = corner
        r.edges = edge
        results.append(r)
        name = "result"+ str(j) + ".png"
        print(name)
        final.save(name)    
    else:
        for index in edge:
            left_index = result[i - 1]
            ***important parts***
            loss, a_diff, piece = match_left_right(puzzle[left_index].clone_piece(), puzzle[index].clone_piece())
            pieces[index] = piece
            loss_dic[loss] = index
            if min_loss == 0 or loss < min_loss:
                min_index = index
                min_loss = loss

        s = sorted(loss_dic.keys())
        l = []
        for j in s:
            # p, r, c, e = 0,0,0,0
            if abs(j - min_loss) <= LOSS_RANGE:
                index = loss_dic[j]
                print(index, " : ", j)
                t = deepcopy(puzzle[index])
                puzzle[index] = pieces[index]
                result[i] = index
                ***important parts***
                p, r, c, e = copyPuzzle(puzzle), deepcopy(result), deepcopy(corner), deepcopy(edge)
                finish_top_line(puzzle, r ,c, e,results)

                puzzle = p
                puzzle[index] = t
            else:
                break
```

there are two places here i have attempted to cope the objects in some way to avoid changes done to the args in the function from affecting outside.

function bellow is the function called to copy a dictionary of object. here deepcopy wasn't working.

```
def copyPuzzle(puzzle):
    p = {}
    for i in list(puzzle.keys()):
        p[i] = (puzzle[i].clone_piece())
    return p
```

this is the function clone function coded under the object.

```
def clone_piece(self):
    t = Piece()
    t.edge_type = deepcopy(self.edge_type)
    t.corners = deepcopy(self.corners)
    t.img = deepcopy(Image.fromarray(np.uint8(cv2.cvtColor(np.asarray(self.img), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR))))
    t.edge_type = deepcopy(self.edge_type)
    t.index= deepcopy(self.index)
    t.floatCorners = deepcopy(self.floatCorners)
    t =self
    return t
```

that changes done to the data inside the functions are like rotating and resizing images. at the end while testing.. the data seems to get messy with the code goes on and can clearly see each saved image is messier than the one before. so this attempt to pass by value seems to not work. how can i fix this?
how to pass by value properly

Answer (score 1):

```
def clone_piece(self):
    t = Piece()
    t.edge_type = deepcopy(self.edge_type)
    t.corners = deepcopy(self.corners)
    t.img = deepcopy(Image.fromarray(np.uint8(cv2.cvtColor(np.asarray(self.img), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR))))
    t.edge_type = deepcopy(self.edge_type)
    t.index= deepcopy(self.index)
    t.floatCorners = deepcopy(self.floatCorners)
    t =self
    return t
```

Can be changed to

```
def clone_piece(self):
    return deepcopy(self)
```

The mistake you are making is this line just before the return :

```
t = self
```

This is basically cancelling all previous lines

Comment: this answer didnt work, but your answer gave me the idea of what kind of errors to look for. deepcopy doest work for this object. i remove the t =self and  the 3rd line and 6th line duplicates. i was supposed to be another attribute. now its working.. thanks

Comment: Why doesn't deepcopy works ? Is it specific to this class ?

Comment: the image in the class cause some error in deepcopy, that that i change the format and then copy